# Wave propagation transverse waves - dispersive or non-dispersive?

Tags: waves, dispersion, ultrasound

Is the propagation of shear waves (transverse waves) in solid media dispersive or non-dispersive?
I'm thinking here of ultrasonic waves that propagate in quasi-isotropic material (metal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dispersive response is a feature of heterogeneous material. As your material includes heterogeneities and your wavelength in order of heterogeneities length scale, the dispersion phenomena are observed. Anisotropic material has another effect on the received wave pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There is dispersion of shear waves in solid media.  The question is how significant is for your application.  A method based on dispersion of shear waves is used to investigate tissue elasticity.  Bones show measurable dispersion too.  For metals the dispersion may be too small but I don't have data about it.  Isotropy is not relevant for dispersivity.